# Sending real notification after toast received

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, toast, mpns

In a project I'm currently working on, we send some small info across the wire to WP7 device when we send a raw notification.

When the application is in a tombstone state and the user receives the toast message, we can't add the extra baggage in the toast. So we figured we need a way to resend the notification once the user entered the application again.

Anybody has any experience or possible solution for this problem. We are currently looking at a sort of handshaking between client and server. But it all seems a bit drastic for me.

Kind regards,
Tom

Comment: Can't you just ask the server if there is pending data when launching the app?

Comment: The problem is that the server both sends Toast and Raw and that the phone seems to decide which one to show. So at server side we don't know if the application was running or not and we don't know which type the end user received ( toast or raw )

Comment: I would suggest to stop using rawNotifications and use only toast. You can detect when a toast notification is received using the ShellToastNotificationReceived event of your channel. When the event is triggered, query the server to retrieve the payload.

Comment: Mmm good idea, seems more efficient then sending both.. :) - In case you want cred for you answer, copy past and i'll marque it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to stop using rawNotifications and use only toast.

To handle the case when the app has been started using a toast notification, query the server at app startup to check if there's pending data.

For notifications sent while the app is running, you can detect them using the ShellToastNotificationReceived event of your channel. When the event is triggered, query the server to retrieve the payload.